# How to prevent macOS double-space from inputting ". " period?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts

In macOS when I type a word and then spacebar twice to type two spaces, a period and a space are entered after the word.

<kbd>" "</kbd> + <kbd>" "</kbd> enters `". "`

This is similar to the (useful!) shortcut in iOS. But I don't want to use that shortcut on my Mac.

How can I prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

System Preferences > Keyboard > Text

> Add period with double-space

[image]

In locales in which a Period is known as a Full Stop, the preferences is titled:

> Add full stop with double-space

Answer (score 3):

In more recent versions of MacOS, this has been moved to:

> Settings → Keyboard → Text Input → Input Sources → Edit → Add period with double-space

[image: Step 1: Find the Edit button]
[image: Step 2: Find the switch labeled “Add period with double-space”]